# How can I find all questions that were migrated from a specific other SE site to Math SE?

Tags: support, migration, search

How can I find all questions migrated from another SE site to Mathematics SE? Specifically I am interested in the ones that have originally come from Physics SE.

So can somebody tell me how to find them from using the search bar for example? Or what methods do exist to get all of them listed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google `"migrated from physics" site:math.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Ha thanks, this works! And there are 24 papges of Google results ...

Comment: Additionally, the 'migrated' tab on the $10k+$ users page has all migrations.